# Application Insights does not capture information level logging

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I have a simple Asp.Net Core Web API application. For this example I have followed the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "InstrumentationKey": "my-instrumentation-key",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApiMonitoring", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            _logger.LogTrace("--- {time}: Logging LogTrace. Value {value}", now, 0);
            _logger.LogDebug("--- {time}: Logging LogDebug. Value {value}", now, 1);
            _logger.LogInformation("--- {time}: Logging LogInformation. Value {value}", now, 2);
            _logger.LogWarning("--- {time}: Logging LogWarning. Value {value}", now, 3);
            _logger.LogError("--- {time}: Logging LogError. Value {value}", now, 4);
            _logger.LogCritical("--- {time}: Logging LogCritical. Value {value}", now, 5);

            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

When running the application locally I can see all the logs levels as expected.

[image]

But Application Insights for the same request is only capturing warning level logs and up. This following image if from Live Metrics in Application Insights.

[image]

The same goes when querying logs in Application Insights.

[image]

What else it is needed for an application to log information level and be captured by Application Insights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your config is wrong. The LogLevel needs to be specified under the Logging section

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "InstrumentationKey": "my-instrumentation-key",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

A valid config would be

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "my-instrumentation-key",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson)

Comment: Thank you! I read those docs a dozen times myself and kept missing the fact that the "ApplicationInsights" object was WITHIN the Logging section.

Comment: But is it required to place ApplicationInsights inside Lgging? Shouldn't the LogLevel and Default setting not apply to all providers including ApplicationInsights? I've noticed if I don't specify ApplicationInsights under Logging then I don't see any Information messages even though this is set ""Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },

Comment: @OliverNilsen when you leave out the App Insights configuration it will default to log anything with a severity of warning a higher. As to why it does not honor the default settings I don't know.