# Azure Function Application Insights Logging not Honoring Host.json Configuration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, host.json

I have enabled Application insights for a function app and traces are being logged successfully, however currently messages from *all* log levels are being included in the Application insights traces table. I have configured my host.json like so, which according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2) should log "Information" and above for Function, Trace and above for Host.Results, and nothing else.

```
{
 "version": "2.0",
 "logging": {
  "logLevel": {
    "default": "None",
    "Host.Results": "None",
    "Function": "Information",
    "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
  },
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "excludedTypes": "Dependency;Request;PageView",
      "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20,
      "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
        "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true,
        "enableW3CDistributedTracing": false,
        "enableResponseHeaderInjection": false
      }
    }
  }
},
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
   "extensions": {
   "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:01",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:15",
            "batchSize": 1,
            "newBatchThreshold": 2,
            "maxDequeueCount": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tested with the following logLevel value which should prevent any traces from being logged

```
"logLevel": {
    "default": "None",
  },
```

Finally, I have attempted to define the logLevel inside the application insights subsection as well as inside the logging section, like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416109/application-insights-does-not-capture-information-level-logging/69418266#69418266), but this also has no effect and does not seem to be a valid config per the [host.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json).

Modifying the logLevel section *does* correctly change the console log level when running the function locally, but has no effect on what is logged in Application insights. I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue. We are unable to use Application insights at the moment because the quantity of data being logged is too great and it is driving our costs up.

Edit: Added complete host.json

Comment: Setting the loglevel for application insights does need to be done inside the application subsection inside the loggin section as stated in my references answer, see [the example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging). Can you post your full host.json including the app insights subsection?

Comment: @PeterBons I've updated the question with my complete host.json. The app insights subsection is inside the logging section

Comment: Ok, but the loglevel inside the app insights section is still missing?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#start-up-and-configuration) in isolated Azure functions, you need to remove default Application insights filters. Then you will be able to configure logging level by `host.json`

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
            // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function app and integrated application insights to it.

- Then I have created a Timmer trigger function app in my local and connected to application insight through adding instrumentation key.
- Iam able to run the function app and tracing the logs in my insight but, Iam getting all the default & function logs in same trace table only. So, to overcome from that I have taken log levels please check the below file.

**host.json :**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information",
        "Host.Results": "Information",
        "Function": "Information",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
        "Function.Function1.User": "Trace",
        "Function.Function1.System": "Debug"

      },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Dependency;Request;PageView",
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20,
        "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
          "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true,
          "enableW3CDistributedTracing": false,
          "enableResponseHeaderInjection": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:01",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:15",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 2,
      "maxDequeueCount": 2
    }
  }
}
```

- Below is my sample **function app** code.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, ILogger logger)
    {

        logger.LogInformation("This is an information-level log message.");
        logger.LogWarning("This is a warning-level log message.");
        logger.LogError("This is an error-level log message.");
        logger.LogTrace("This is a trace-level log message.");
        logger.LogDebug("This is a debug-level log message.");
        logger.LogCritical("This is a critical-level log message.");
    }
}
```

- Iam able to run successfully by communicating with host.json file.

[image]
[image]

- Iam able to see the function logs with separation by security levels

**Query :**

```
traces
| where severityLevel in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
| order by timestamp desc
```

**Results :**
[image]
[image]
[image]